# How to compile multiple proto files with one command from multiple directories

Tags: cmd, proto

I have the following structure:

rootfolder/

```
foldA
  A1.proto
foldB
  B1.proto
foldC
  C1.proto
```

what I tried is:
`for /r %g in (*.proto) do protoc -I=rootfolder --python_out=. %g`

Ideally I would want to compile them all in a folder named protos at rootfolder level. Also I can't hardcode them because im supposed to do a command which would compile other proto files added in the future as well.
The error I get with my command is:

> <full_path_to_proto_file> File does not reside within any path specified using --proto_path (or -I). You must specify a --proto_path which encompasses this file. Note that the proto_path must be an exact prefix of the .proto file name -- protoc is too dumb to figure out when two paths (eg absolute and relative) are equivalent.

Comment: `for /D %J in ("rootfolder\*") do for %I in ("%~J\*.proto") do protoc --proto_path="%~dpI." --python_out="%~dpJprotos" "%~nxI"`?

Comment: @aschipfl thank you for the quick response, unfortunately when I tried out your wizardly command nothing happened. No error no nothing.

Comment: I do not know the `protoc` tool, so the command line might be wrong (perhaps it does not accept quotation?). Anyway, just insert `ECHO` to check what the `for` loops do – `… do ECHO protoc …`…

Comment: ok i got it running with your wizard command and what the echo returns is: 

```echo protoc --proto_path="path_to_folder" --python_out="path_to_protos_folder" "name_of_proto_file" protoc --proto_path="path_to_folder" --python_out="path_to_protos_folder" "name_of_proto_file"```

basically it runs the command twice?


edit: i think your command works perfectly fine and the issue lies elsewhere because when I run the command now without the echo the cmd tells me "path_to_proto_file": file not found with a few cases here and there telling me it was either not found or has errors in it

Comment: @aschipfl i fixed it! just made the python_out to be relative instead of the full path and it worked! thank you for you help bro this wouldve taken AGES if not for you mr wizard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the kind user in the comment section of my post

`for /D %J in ("rootfolder\*") do for %I in ("%~J\*.proto") do protoc --proto_path="%~dpI." --python_out="protos" "%~nxI"`